# Usable Implementations to decide the existential theory of the reals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms

I guess many have heard of the existential theory of the reals:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals

I have read in various papers that the problem lies in PSPACE. I have frequently some problems that I would like to solve by some of these algorithms. As I am often concerned with small finite instances I don't mind if the computation takes several days. Can someone recommend me a usable implementation?

Preferably, non-commercial.

Apparently SAGE has only a "use at your own risk" version.

Also I am not interested in numerical solutions.

best
Till

Comment: Algebraic Geometry???

Comment: @abx, the tag is appropriate:  this is looking for implemented algorithms in real algebraic geometry

Comment: Seems promising, but I am not certain of its relevance: Gao, Sicun, Soonho Kong, and Edmund M. Clarke. "dReal: An SMT solver for nonlinear theories over the reals." *International Conference on Automated Deduction*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2013.
[Journal link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-38574-2_14)

Comment: I guess a list of SMT-solvers can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories . However I have not found one that uses cylindrical algebraic decompositions. Has anyone experience with those solvers for ETR?

Comment: QEPCAD implements cylindrical algebraic decompositions: https://www.usna.edu/CS/qepcadweb/B/QEPCAD.html